# No candies From Eggs

Tags: pokemon-go

So this has happened a while ago, but I watch hatching eggs, 3 eggs at the same time and then two other ones at the same time. When they hatched, I received no candies at all... I don't know if it was just a glitch or something but does anyone know why I received no candies?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get candy? Is it possible you just missed the animation of the little bubble showing that you got it because it fades out?

Answer (score -1):

firstly, check the pokemon that hatched, then see how many candies for each of them you have

if they appear to be a bit higher then you have recieved the candies

## if not

then contact pokemon go using the "report high priorirty issues" link and they should be able to resolve it